# Set Builder Notation on predicate

Tags: logic, second-order-logic

With Set Builder Notation, one usually create sets of individuals based on some conditions, eg. $S=\{x|P(x)\}$ as the set of all individuals that satisfy $P(x)$.

I was wondering if we could use Set Builder Notation to create kind of the opposite: sets of properties based on an individual. For instance, if we consider $P_1a, \cdots, P_na$ properties that $a$ satisfies, could we construct the set $P=\{Px|Pa\}$ ?

Moreover, could we create a set that include all properties of any arity that $a$ satisfy? Maybe with something like $P'=\{Px|a \in x\}$?

Comment: If you can enumerate the set of properties that interest you, then sure.  If you're thinking that the set of all properties is something you can work with, you will run into the "naive" of "naive set theory" pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: A quick note/question.
A set $P$ of arity 1 is a collection $\{a_1, \cdots, a_n\}$.
A set $P$ of arity $\geq$ 2 is a collection such as $\langle x_1, x_2 \rangle$ for $P^2$, such as $\langle \langle x_1, x_2\rangle, x_3 \rangle$ for $P^3$, etc.
"$\langle x_1, x_2 \rangle$" is just another way to write "$\{\{x_1\}, \{x_1, x_2\}\}$".

Thus, for $P = \{Px | a \in x\}$, there will never be a $P^{k\geq 2}$,
because for any $a$, $a \notin P^{k\geq 2}$, since only  collections
$\langle x_1, \cdots, x_k\rangle$ are in $P^{k\geq 2}$.
Is that right?